# Google TV emulator and GenericMotionEvent

Tags: android, emulation, google-tv

I would like to process the pointer hover event in my google tv application but without any success.

As I understand from the documentation I must set `OnGenericMotionListener` listener for my widget, but it seems the `onGenericMotion()` method does not called.

The constructor of my widget looks like this:

```
public MyWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

    super(context, attrs);
    setOnGenericMotionListener(new OnGenericMotionListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onGenericMotion(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         Log.d("","Motion");
         return false;
       });     
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have not real device and must to develop in Google tv emulator.
Is it restriction of the emulator or am I making something wrong?

Comment: email me lesv (at) google.com

Comment: Shouldn't your MyWidget extend the View class?

Comment: I inherit it from RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing your code on a Google TV device and it works as expected.
So this seems like a bug or limitation with the emulator. Please file it in the Google TV Issue tracker.